# SQL Server - using Over/Partition By in complex query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have many complex queries which involve a lot of columns and joins (see the example below) that are implemented as views.

In some cases these queries return duplicate rows which then have to be programmatically removed by the consuming app. Therefore, we would like to enhance the SQL query to eliminate the duplicates, and speed up the retrieval process.

I know that I can use `OVER / PARTITION BY` logic to do this, but I am not sure of how to modify the queries to obtain a working syntax.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT
    Main.MfgOrder.OrderNumber,
    Main.MfgOrder.DesignBOMID,
    Main.Design_Plant.PlantID,
    Main.MfgOrder_Operation.OrderOpID,
    Main.MfgOrder_Operation.DesignOpID,
    Main.MfgOrder_Operation.OpSeq, 
    Main.MfgOrder_Operation.Description,
    Main.MfgOrder_Operation.CompletionStatus,
    Main.MfgOrder__Shift.OrderShiftID,
    Main.MfgOrder__Shift.WorkCenterMachineID,
    Main.MfgOrder___Event.OrderEventID,
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.OrderReelID,
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.ReelNumber,
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.Location, 
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.Test_Status AS Test_Status_Reel,
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.Test_Disposition AS Test_Disposition_Reel,
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.LabReleased,
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel.ShipReelsBypassSet,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.OrderLengthID,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.LengthType, 
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.LocationOnReel,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.LocationOnLength, 
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.TrialNumber,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.SampleNumber, 
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.PrintNumber,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.Test_Status AS Test_Status_Length,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.Test_Category,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.Test_Disposition AS Test_Disposition_Length,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.SampleSubmittedBy,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.SampleSubmittedDate,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length.BypassTesting,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length_OperatorQty.Sample1Destination,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length_OperatorQty.Sample2Destination,
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length_OperatorQty.Sample3Destination,
    Main.MfgOrder______Component.OrderComponentID,
    Main.MfgOrder______Component.DesignComponentID,
    Main.MfgOrder______Component.ItemNo, 
    Main.MfgOrder_______Test.LabTestID,
    Main.MfgOrder_______Test.OrderTestID,
    Main.MfgOrder_______Test.TestComplete,
    Main.MfgOrder_______Test.TestStatus,
    Main.MfgOrder________Marker2.OrderMarkerID,
    Master.Color.ColorName,
    Master.LabTest.ExcludeFromPassFail,
    CASE 
       WHEN Main.Design_Component.Component_Label IS NULL 
          THEN 'Unknown' 
          ELSE Main.Design_Component.Component_Label 
    END AS Component_Label
FROM
    Main.MfgOrder
INNER JOIN 
    Main.Design__BOM ON Main.MfgOrder.DesignBOMID = Main.Design__BOM.DesignBOMID
INNER JOIN 
    Main.Design_Plant ON Main.Design__BOM.DesignPlantID = Main.Design_Plant.DesignPlantID
INNER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder_Operation ON Main.MfgOrder.OrderNumber = Main.MfgOrder_Operation.OrderNumber
INNER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder__Shift ON Main.MfgOrder_Operation.OrderOpID = Main.MfgOrder__Shift.OrderOpID
INNER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder___Event ON Main.MfgOrder__Shift.OrderShiftID = Main.MfgOrder___Event.OrderShiftID
INNER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder____Reel ON Main.MfgOrder___Event.OrderEventID = Main.MfgOrder____Reel.OrderEventID
INNER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length ON Main.MfgOrder____Reel.OrderReelID = Main.MfgOrder_____Length.OrderReelID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   Main.MfgOrder______Component ON Main.MfgOrder_____Length.OrderLengthID = Main.MfgOrder______Component.OrderLengthID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder_______Test ON Main.MfgOrder______Component.OrderComponentID = Main.MfgOrder_______Test.OrderComponentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder________Marker2 ON Main.MfgOrder_______Test.OrderTestID = Main.MfgOrder________Marker2.OrderTestID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Main.Design_Component ON Main.MfgOrder______Component.DesignComponentID = Main.Design_Component.DesignComponentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Master.Color ON Main.MfgOrder______Component.TapeColorID = Master.Color.ColorNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Master.LabTest ON Main.MfgOrder_______Test.LabTestID = Master.LabTest.LabTestID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Main.MfgOrder_____Length_OperatorQty ON Main.MfgOrder______Component.OrderLengthID = Main.MfgOrder_____Length_OperatorQty.OrderLengthID
```

Comment: Which ID column is it that is showing as a dupe? It could just be that it is possible to resolve in the join. But, if you can advise which ID it is that is duplicating, should be able to assist how you have asked.

Comment: over partition makes sense with aggregation, in this case I don't think you can use window functions

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number as below: Below query will not select duplicate only on OrderNumber, if you need to add other columns you add accordingly

```
Select * from (
    Select 
         RowN = Row_Number() over( partition by Main.MfgOrder.OrderNumber order by Main.MfgOrder.OrderNumber),
         --- All your select columns and all your query with joins
  ) a
  Where a.RowN = 1
```

Comment: the OP is not asking how to dedupe but how to improve the query to avoid dupes

Comment: try create table with your query and after using row_number.

Comment: Answers to the above questions:

Comment: Answers to the above questions:

1. We cannot use either group by or select distinct because the duplicate only occur in 4 of the columns.

2. The columns that need unduping in this case are: Main.MfgOrder.OrderNumber, Main.MfgOrder_Operation.OrderOpID, Main.MfgOrder____Reel.ReelNumber, and Main.MfgOrder_____Length.SampleNumber

3.  It looks like the answer suggested by Kannan may work - will try that - Thanks

Comment: The above suggestion by Kannan resolved the issue - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the entire row duplicated exactly? If so then just add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ...
FROM
    ...
```

If you are getting duplicate rows where most columns the same but some columns are different then `GROUP BY` the columns that are the same and select `MIN(column_name)` for the ones that are causing the extra rows to appear.